# Show the following homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Source: Conover, *A First Course in Topology*

> **Lemma 2.16.**
> Let $\{X_\lambda :\lambda \in \Lambda\}$ be a nonempty collection of nonempty topological spaces.
> Let $x\in\prod X_\lambda$ and $n$ be a positive integer.
> For $\lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_n$ put
> $$
>   A_\lambda=\begin{cases}
>   X_\lambda& \text{if $\lambda=\lambda_i$, $1\le i\le n$,}\\
>   \{x_\lambda\} &\text{if $\lambda\ne\lambda_i$, $1\le i\le n$.}
>   \end{cases}
>   $$
> Then $\prod A_\lambda$ is homeomorphic to $\prod X_\lambda$ where $\prod A_\lambda$ has product topology.

I know what a homeomorphism is.
Show $f$ is a bijection, continuous and the inverse is
too between two sets.

**My Attempt**

Let $U\subseteq A_\lambda$ be open.
Suppose $\lambda \ne \lambda_i$ for $1\le i\le n$.
Let $f\colon \{x_\lambda \}\mapsto\prod X_\lambda$.
Then for $\lambda \in\Lambda$, $\pi_\lambda \circ f(U) $ is continuous.

I doubt if this is any good. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Format it better and choose better notation so we can understand what it is you're asking. As it stands it makes no sense to me and I'm not gonna guess.

Comment: I don’t know how to do brackets,so I will put up an image

Comment: There is a mathjax tutorial on the site BTW

Comment: The image is up

Comment: So $A_\lambda$ is just a homeomorph of a finite product of the $X_{\lambda_i}$? But do the finite sets vary at all? $A_\lambda$ does not depend on $\lambda$ but on the fixed point $x$ and the finite set $\{\lambda_1, \ldots , \lambda_n\}$. It's a weird notation.

Comment: I thought I was dealing with infinite product.

Comment: That's irrelevant to the notational and clarity matter.

Comment: This theorem is a generalized version of the following Let X and Y be topological spaces and let X x Y have product topology. Then X and Y are each homeomorphic to a subspace of X x Y

Comment: Yes, that when we take the finite set as a singleton in essence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we fix $x \in \prod_{\lambda \in \Lambda} X_\lambda$ and define $A(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)$ as you do, but you name it $A_\lambda$ (a misnomer), it's easy to see that $A(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n) \simeq \prod_{i=1}^n X_{\lambda_i}$ so connected (by earlier results on finite connected products) when all $X_\lambda$ are.

And by the definition of the product topology it's clear that

$$\bigcup_{\{\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n\} \text{ a finite subset of } \Lambda} A(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)$$ is dense in $\prod_{\lambda \in \Lambda} X_\lambda$ making that product also connected, because the union is connected as a union of connected subspaces that all contain $x$.

So your defined set is just a finite product topologically. The bijection is trivial and trivially continuous as well.

Comment: Conover has some weird stuff in his book

Comment: @HomerSimpson Well, this is pretty standard stuff.

Comment: That is Conover’s terminology @Henno Brandsma